# Why can't I change the frame of my UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, frame

I have been trying for two days to modify the frame of a `UILabel`, which
is ridiculous... The `UILabel` is an IBOutlet, but that is not the reason
why it's not working: I tried to create a `UILabel` programatically and
it still didn't work. Here is how I do it:

```
self.descriptionLabel.text = description;
self.descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

CGSize textSize = [self.descriptionLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]
                                         constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.descriptionLabel.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)
                                             lineBreakMode:self.descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode];
CGFloat frameHeight = textSize.height;
CGRect frame = self.descriptionLabel.frame;
frame.size.height = frameHeight;
self.descriptionLabel.frame = frame;

CGRect bounds = self.descriptionLabel.frame;
bounds.origin.x = self.descriptionLabel.frame.origin.x + 10.0;
bounds.size.width = self.descriptionLabel.frame.size.width - 20.0;
self.descriptionLabel.bounds = bounds;
self.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

I already asked on IRC and they told me that there is no reason why the
frame would not be changed...

I also tried to create a frame with `CGRectMake` and give it arbitrary
value but that didn't do the trick either..

Does anyone know what might be the problem please?

**Edit 1:** I logged the frame before and after, and I got odd results:

```
Before: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
After: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 33525.000000
```

The height after I set the frame is the only value that makes sense (I have a lot of text in the label on purpose).

**Edit 2:** I changed the code as follows, the log says that the frame
changed but on the simulator it didn't change; I proved it by adding red
borders to the layer of the `UILabel`.

```
self.descriptionLabel.text = description;
self.descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

CGSize textSize = [self.descriptionLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]
                                         constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)
                                             lineBreakMode:self.descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode];
CGFloat frameHeight = textSize.height;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 300.0, self.view.frame.size.width, frameHeight);
self.descriptionLabel.frame = frame;

DDLogInfo(@"After: %f %f %f %f", self.descriptionLabel.frame.origin.x, self.descriptionLabel.frame.origin.y, self.descriptionLabel.frame.size.width, self.descriptionLabel.frame.size.height);
// After: 0.000000 300.000000 320.000000 585.000000

self.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.descriptionLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
self.descriptionLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2;
```

[image: Proof]

Comment: Did you log the frame before and after? And why are you changing the bounds (particularly by using the frame, which is in a different coordinate space)?

Comment: I logged the frame before and after as you suggested and I got odd results that I included in the question that I editted.

Comment: Why are you setting the number of lines to 0 at the end?

Comment: @Abizern From what I read, it makes the number of lines "dynamic" or whatever you wanna call it. I found this on SO. But anyway, uncommenting the line doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're using auto layout, you shouldn't be doing any setting of frames -- either turn off auto layout, or use constraints to change the size of your label. The easiest way to do this is to give your label a height constraint (and width too, if you want a constant width) in IB, and make an IBOutlet to it. Then, in code, change the constant value of that constraint based on the value you get from sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:.

Comment: Worked great.  It's not obvious how to update the constraint.  Here is how you do it:  self.labelWidthContraint.constant = size.width; self.labelHeightContraint.constant = size.height;

Comment: Not exactly intuitive, but this worked nicely - thanks Mr. Delmar!

Comment: @rizzes, yes it has. Now you should use 
boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context: instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your label has a zero frame to begin with, so, when you do this:

```
CGSize textSize = [self.descriptionLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]
                                         constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.descriptionLabel.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)
                                             lineBreakMode:self.descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

You're asking the `sizeWithFont` method to do something effectively impossible - tell you the height that is required when no width is allowed. The response it provides (33525.000000) is probably the height if one character is allowed on each line or something like that.

So, either set the width of the label before you start, or provide the allowed width to the `sizeWithFont` method and then set the label size using the response (not just the height).

Also, consider what you're trying to do by changing the bounds. Comment that code out till you get the frame right at least, then you can add it back in and check it actually does what you want.

Comment: Please see my latest edit. I followed your suggestions and in the log the frame changed but it didn't do a thing in the simulator...

Comment: And that's the only code you have that does anything to the label? Where is that code at (what method is it in and when is it called)? What auto-resizing / auto-layout rules does it have?

Comment: I added the UILabel from IB and I didn't touch the auto-layout constraints. Here is the full file where this code is in: https://gist.github.com/AzizLight/40b66b2daa2917952d6f As you can see the UILabel is setup in `viewDidLoad` and that's about it...